# replacing nums with data values

Tags: sql-server, mysql

I have a table with column 'columnx' with values (1,2,1,NULL,1,1,3)

| Column X | Column Y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 |
| Null | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |

and I am hoping to replace these num with actual data from another table 'X1' as follows:

| Enum Val | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | red |
| 2 | blue |
| 3 | green |
| 4 | yellow |

so the output should like this:

| Column X | Column Y |
| --- | --- |
| red | 3 |
| blue | 3 |
| red | 1 |
| Null | 1 |
| red | 1 |
| red | 1 |

I need to do the same for column Y as well for which the data is sourced from a different table and has different values for the corresponding enum

all the tables are in the same DB, I was hoping to use REPLACE but unable to follow through

what would be the best way to do it if the columns are static?

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by REPLEACE you mean update the values on the table a simple inner join update clause would do the trick.

[MySQL example](https://dbfiddle.uk/Nrssq1Tz)

```
update my_table m
inner join x1 on x1.EnumVal=m.ColumnX
set m.ColumnX=x1.Description
```

[SQL Server example](https://dbfiddle.uk/K9kRMukW)

```
update  m
set m.ColumnX=x1.Description
from my_table m
inner join x1 on x1.EnumVal=m.ColumnX
```

Given data example

```
create table my_table (
ColumnX varchar(15) ,
ColumnY varchar(15) );

insert into my_table values (1,3), (2,3),(1,1),(Null,1),(1,1),(1,1);

create table x1 (
EnumVal int ,
Description varchar(15));

insert into x1 values (1,'red'),(2,'blue'),(3,'green'),(4,'yellow');
```

> Result
>
> ```
> ColumnX   ColumnY
>   red     3
>   blue    3
>   red     1
>   null    1
>   red     1
>   red     1
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)